# mysql error: ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql

I am facing an issue with a mysql query. I need to copy data from one table to another table. The query I am using is:

`mysql> insert into voucher (code, amount, expire_at, state, driver_id, asset_account_id, created_at, updated_at, creator_id, agent, voucher_batch_id, image, city_id, country_id, serial_number, updater_id, redeemed_at) select (code, amount, expire_at, state, driver_id, asset_account_id, created_at, updated_at, creator_id, agent, voucher_batch_id, image, city_id, country_id, serial_number, updater_id, redeemed_at) from voucher_log ;`

But, I am getting the below error on executing this:

> ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: Please format your code as code & quotes as quotes. Please google your error message without specific names. What happens when you simplify your query until there is no error then add stuff back? Please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
insert into voucher 
    (code, amount, expire_at, state, driver_id, asset_account_id, created_at, updated_at, creator_id, agent, voucher_batch_id, image, city_id, country_id, serial_number, updater_id, redeemed_at) 
select 
    (code, amount, expire_at, state, driver_id, asset_account_id, created_at, updated_at, creator_id, agent, voucher_batch_id, image, city_id, country_id, serial_number, updater_id, redeemed_at) 
from voucher_log ;
```

your query should be

```
insert into 
    voucher (code, amount, expire_at, state, driver_id, asset_account_id, created_at, updated_at, creator_id, agent, voucher_batch_id, image, city_id, country_id, serial_number, updater_id, redeemed_at) 
select 
    code, amount, expire_at, state, driver_id, asset_account_id, created_at, updated_at, creator_id, agent, voucher_batch_id, image, city_id, country_id, serial_number, updater_id, redeemed_at 
from voucher_log ;
```

you are putting `()` in the select query. that part is wrong.

Comment: Thanks @smn_onrocks, it works!